# Troubles proving $O[f(n)] \cdot O[g(n)] = O[f(n) \cdot g(n)]$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

> Prove that $O[f(n)] \cdot O[g(n)] = O[f(n) \cdot g(n)]$, knowing that $O[g(n)] = \left\{ f(n) \mid \exists\ c,n_0 > 0\ :\ 0 \leq f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)\ \forall\ n \geq n_0 \right\}$

I don't really know what to do here. I tried to use the definition to relate the first part of the equality with the second:

Be $x(n) \in O[f(n)] \cdot O[g(n)]$, $\implies 0 \leq x(n) \leq cf(n)$ and $0 \leq x(n) \leq cg(n)\ \forall\ n \geq n_0$.

But I got stuck trying to find a connection between the two inequalities.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ purposely used in two different contexts here? Or are the $f,g$ in the first equation different from the $f,g$ as in the definition of $O[g(n)]$?

Comment: @T.Eskin Sorry, my mistake. They are different from the definition.

Comment: see big O notation, wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Pro-tip: $O(f)=f \cdot O(1)$, hence you are left to show that $O(1)O(1)=O(1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we have $x(n)\in O[f(n)]\cdot O[g(n)]$. This means that there exists $y(n)\in O[f(n)]$ and $z(n)\in O[g(n)]$ and $c_1, n_{1}, c_2, n_2>0$ such that $x(n)=y(n)\cdot z(n)$ and $0\leq y(n)\leq c_1 f(n)$ and $0\leq z(m)\leq c_2 g(m)$ for all $n\geq n_1$, $m\geq n_2$. Take $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
x(n)=y(n)z(n)\leq c_1 c_2 f(n)g(n)
\end{align*}
for all $n\geq n_0$. So $x(n)$ satisfies the condition of $O[f(n)g(n)]$ with $n_{0}$ and constant $c_1 c_2$. So $O[f(n)]\cdot O[g(n)]\subseteq O[f(n)g(n)]$. I'll leave you to complete the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Now I see the realtionship! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've studied your answer, and have a doubt. Why is $x(n) = y(n) \cdot z(n)$? When using sets, isn't $x(n)$ in both $O[f(n)]$ and $O[g(n)]$?

Comment: @JBFWP286. If $x(n)\in O[f(n)]\cdot O[g(n)]$, this means that $x(n)$ is a product of a $O[f(n)]$ and a $O[g(n)]$ function. Both of these functions might have different constants $n_1,c_1$ and $n_2,c_2$, but for $x(n)$ to be $O[f(n)g(n)]$, there should be constants $c,n_0$ that work uniformly for both $f$ and $g$, which we showed is possible. Once you have also proved the reverse inclusion, which is the more trivial part, then by set notations, we see that indeed $O[f(n)]\cdot O[g(n)]=O[f(n)g(n)]$.